# Postgres overlapping dates query - see if two dates as a range overlap a month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing a query to see if a date range [start_date] - [end_date] overlap a month.

So far I have:

```
select * from my table
where (start_date, end_date) overlaps ('2000-02-01', '2000-02-28')
```

I need it to contain date ranges that start outside of the month but go into the month, or start in the month and go into the next month:
e.g.

`'2000-01-31', '2000-02-01'
 '2000-02-28', '2000-03-01'`

however these are not being included in the query result.

It would also be great if I could just put the datepart of the month instead of overlaps ('2000-02-01', '2000-02-28')

Any help appreciated

Comment: I think you need to avoid the use of the actual begin and end dates of a month because they vary too much, up-voted your question because this actually made my brain crack and I'm curious for the result :)

Comment: In Standard SQL `overlaps` works on periods where the start is included, but the end is excluded (you could adjust that by adding a day to the end). What about ranges when they start before that month and end after it? Or ranges within that month?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html):

```
select * 
from the_table
where daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') && daterange(date '2000-02-01', date '2000-02-28', '[]')
```

The parameter `'[]'` creates an "inclusive" range. This will also work properly for partial or multiple months (and can even be indexed efficiently)

Answer (score 2):

I would just be explicit:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (start_date < '2000-02-01' and end_date >= '2000-02-01')
      (end_date  > '2000-02-28' and start_date <= '2000-02-28'
```

Comment: This only works for one month, I know it's the example, but what would be a more abstract way to tackle this problem? Is there a way, or does every month need to be hard-coded? What about leap-years?

Comment: If you use Standard SQL's inclusive-exclusive periods there's no need to know about the end of a month, e.g. February 2000 is from '2000-02-01' to '2000-03-01' :-)

Comment: @Nebulosar . . . I don't get your point at all.  This is tied to two dates, not to months.  You simply need to plug in the dates.